# How to pass database name dynamically in ZIO Zlayer dependency

Tags: scala, zio

Problem: I use a different database for every customer (each one has a separate sub-domain) extracted from the domain name. e.g. customer1.abc.com then a database name, "db_customer1" is used for PostgreSQL DB connections (e.g In line 31 of https://github.com/pawank/zio-playground/blob/master/src/main/scala/dev/xymox/zio/playground/zhttp/ItemEndpoints.scala new db information is to be used).

zio-http is to be used for the implementation (e.g https://github.com/pawank/zio-playground/blob/master/src/main/scala/dev/xymox/zio/playground/zhttp/ItemServer.scala).

How do I either pass a database name in every repository function which can be used by db library or provide zlayer dynamically with new db name other than what is taken from the config file. (In the example code at line 21 of https://github.com/pawank/zio-playground/blob/master/src/main/scala/dev/xymox/zio/playground/zhttp/ItemServer.scala the data source `ZioQuillContext.dataSourceLayer` is statically set.

Any suggestion to provide the layer dependency within HTTP methods?

Steps to run minimal reproducible example:
$sbt
$run
(Choose no 40 for example)
[git@github.com:pawank/zio-playground.git](http://git@github.com:pawank/zio-playground.git)

Comment: Can you please create a [MCVE] of your problem?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Here is a repo on github: git@github.com:pawank/zio-playground.git

Comment: that is actually not a trivial issue. If you want to make it typesafe, then you will need to do research and pass multiple instances of `dataSourceLayer`. They must have different types. Only this way you will be able to extract it using `ZIO.access`. The other way is to make your own custom `dataSourceLayer` that contains all of database connections. This way you will be able to extract this evn. and after that extract database that you need (by name, for example). There is no good-looking standard approach in zio for this issue. At least not in popular database integration tools.

Comment: Thanks, @BogdanVakulenko So, essentially I need to load the config for all databases at once and then use it via ZIO access. Let me try it out.